# Is there any random number generator in C other than rand()?

Tags: c, random

I want to generate random numbers in C which are extremely random. Is there any other function than rand()? I am using windows and gcc compiler. If it is from any other library, please mention the header file.

Comment: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it"_

Comment: Which OS? compiler? gcc offers *random()* from stdlib (BSD, POSIX)..

Comment: POSIX provides the [`drand48()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/drand48.html) family of random number functions, but there isn't anything else in Standard C — the alternatives are all somewhat platform specific. Some platforms provide `/dev/urandom` and `/dev/random`, for example; reading from those gives you high quality random data. One advantage of `drand48()` (and `rand()`) is that you can guarantee repeatability when you want it (as well as randomness when you want it). `/dev/random` won't give you that. What do you need it for? Cryptography is another game…

Comment: In standard C, no, as a compiler or third party library/extension, probably hundreds of varying quality.

Answer (score 1):

yes

you can use `arc4random()`. This will give you more random number than `rand()`.

Answer (score 1):

The mersenne twister is considered a good RNG. Good randomness, fast but it can be predictable if you don't take steps.

Here you can find some versions:

http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/C-LANG/c-lang.html

Comment: Mersenne Twister has nice properties, but randomness (defined as: lack of predictability) isn't one of them. And the question asked for "extremely random".

Comment: @Art: Would you care to elaborate on that?  Wikipedia on [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) seems to contradict what you said.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Read the wikipedia article a bit more carefully. "observing a sufficient number of iterations (624 in the case of MT19937, since this is the size of the state vector from which future iterations are produced) allows one to predict all future iterations.".

Comment: Personal rant: I guess it is "random" in the modern, computer science definition of the word "random". Because for some reason computer science has decided that the word "random" should mean "perfectly predictable", with the added requirement that "each run of a program should produce the exact same sequence unless you do some badly defined operation that doesn't help much" and preferably also: "forked child processes should duplicate their sequences". So yes, it is "random" in that sense.

Comment: If you mean "it isn't a cryptographic PRNG", then say so (like Wikipedia does).

Comment: No, I mean it isn't random. It's maybe "computer science random", but the word random outside of programming is usually defined as "lacking predictability and patterns".

Comment: @art Yes it's predictable thats why it cant be used for encryption but, let's say, the randomn distribution of numbers it generates is pretty good. but it will always be pseudo random, true

Comment: Nice discussion, now to find a nice question in which to put it.

Comment: @ServéLaurijssen I wouldn't say "can't be used for encryption". Judging from the never ending stream of screwups people have with bad random I would say "can't be used for anything unless proven otherwise". The attitude that we should use bad PRNGs except for crypto inevitably leads to situations where they are woefully inadequate (because gambling or sessions identifiers aren't "crypto"). We should stop calling non-random things "random". Pick a different word. Especially since there are great CSPRNGs that are within 50% of the performance of the fastest PRNGS.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no other function in standard C to generate random number other than `rand()`. GCC provide [`rand_r()`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/ISO-Random.html) function as an extension.